# Caret: Feature selection with Chi2 / f_classif

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, feature-selection, natural-language, caret

I try to classify texts which I have converted to term-document matrices before. I would like to perform feature selection to reduce the number of predictors. In Python, you can do this by means of the `SelectKBest` function, for example like so:

```
selector = SelectKBest(f_classif, k = 2000)
```

The caret package from R also enables you to employ univariate feature selection; the tutorial section "Feature Selection using Univariate Filters" details the general approach here (https://topepo.github.io/caret/feature-selection-using-univariate-filters.html).

However, I do not understand this sufficiently to be able to build a Chi2 / f_classif feature selection on my own - how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear about what exactly you wanted to do. That said,  `f_classif` does ANOVA for feature selection for you instead of chi-squared.

R package `FSelector` provides chi squared feature selection with function `chi.squared`. Here is the example from the document: https://rdrr.io/cran/FSelector/man/chi.squared.html